# How do you check that a particular memory location is in the cache

Tags: cpu-cache

The recently published Meltdown/Spectre hardware security flaws exploit speculative execution and the memory cache to gain information about the content of memory locations that the executing code is not permitted to access. If I understand the attacks correctly, a crucial final stage of the attack is to determine whether the content of a particular memory location is in the cache. But how can that be done?

I'm an application programmer who uses high level languages, so I'm used to measuring the *average* cache performance of code, through sampling ([profiling](/questions/tagged/profiling)), not the cache performance of a single instruction or memory location. How is it even possible to measure performance at such fine granularity?

Comment: Timing. The Meltdown paper cites the three most-known cache side attacks (Prime+Probe, Flush+Reload, Evict+Time). A summary should be [here](https://conference.hitb.org/hitbsecconf2016ams/materials/D2T1%20-%20Anders%20Fogh%20-%20Cache%20Side%20Channel%20Attacks.pdf)

Comment: @MargaretBloom If it can be done by timing, *how* do you measure the time taken?

Comment: Usually, the wall-clock time stamp counter is used (that counts at 2-3GHz, irrespective of the actual clock). The HPET could also be used if you can configure the application with a direct access to it to trim away syscalls overhead. Considering that a hit in the L1, without any other bottleneck, takes 3-4 cycles to complete versus the hundreds of cycles of a memory access, it should be easy to tell them apart.